# change position fixed to relative, vice-versa in Foundation

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I would like position:fixed to only work when I'm displaying the app on a large screen. If I am in mobile, I don't want position:fixed. What is wrong with my scss? I actually just took the idea from another stackoverflow post.

```
.page {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    @media #{$small} {
      position: relative;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$small` and/or what does the code look like when compiled to CSS?

Comment: Thanks for mention what $small is. Like what I said earlier, I just took the idea from another post. However, I don't have $small variable. Gulp build saw it and it spitted out the error. So if I get rid of @media #{$small} {, what should be the code instead?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and it's working great!

```
.page {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
  .sidebar {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
      position: fixed;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to zurb foundation

```
.page {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
  .sidebar {
        position: relative;
        @media screen and (max-width: 63.9375em), screen and (min-width: 75em) {
            position: fixed;
        }
  }
}
```